# Atom Quokka plugin error: Unexpected token import when importing a module written with ES6 -

Tags: atom-editor, wallaby.js, quokka.js

I am trying to use the wonderful Quokka package by WallabyJS https://github.com/wallabyjs/atom-quokka.

I am trying to import an ES6 module but keep getting an error in the Quokka console:

***Unexpected token import at createScript vm.js:56***

I have tried updating my package.json file and set **babel: true** as advised in the configuration page [here](https://quokkajs.com/docs/configuration.html) but i still get the error.

Link to my package.json file [here](https://github.com/neil-coutinho/es-gulp-babel-intern/blob/master/package.json)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [specify react-app preset](https://github.com/wallabyjs/quokka/issues/31#issuecomment-292053881) in your Quokka config, so instead of "babel: true", you need:

```
babel: {
    presets: ['react-app']
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artem, I updated the package.json and added the above but still get the same error? Am i doing something incorrectly? Git updated 
Link to my  https://github.com/neil-coutinho/es-gulp-babel-intern/blob/master/package.json